# Rails call destroy method from within another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, destroy

I have a `friendships_controller` but I would like to call its `create` and `destroy` actions from inside the `users_controller`. Actually, the way I have things set up, the `create` method works fine, but `destroy` does not.

users/index

```
<%= button_to "+ Add Friend", :controller => "friendships", :action => 'create', :method => "post", :id => user.id %>
<%= button_to "- Unfriend", {:controller => "friendships", :action => 'destroy'}, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to unfriend #{user.username}?", :method => :delete, :id => user.id %>
```

If I click the Unfriend button I get the follow rails exception:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FriendshipsController#destroy
Couldn't find User with ID=destroy
```

This is the `destroy` action within `friendships_controller`:

```
  def destroy
    @accepting_user = User.find(params[:id])
    @friendship = Friendship.find_by_accepting_user_id_and_requesting_user_id(@accepting_user.id, current_user.id)
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "You unfriended #{@friendship.accepting_user.username}."
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Friendship routes:

```
rake routes | grep friendship
           friendships_index GET    /friendships/index(.:format)                                      {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"index"}
                 friendships GET    /friendships(.:format)                                            {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"index"}
                             POST   /friendships(.:format)                                            {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"create"}
              new_friendship GET    /friendships/new(.:format)                                        {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"new"}
             edit_friendship GET    /friendships/:id/edit(.:format)                                   {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"edit"}
                  friendship GET    /friendships/:id(.:format)                                        {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"show"}
                             PUT    /friendships/:id(.:format)                                        {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"update"}
                             DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)                                        {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: I added the routes from friendship above; would you actually prefer to see the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it working, just had to move where I was passing in the `:id`

Final result looks like:

```
<%= button_to "- Unfriend", {:controller => "friendships", :action => 'destroy', :id => user.id}, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to unfriend #{user.username}?", :method => :delete %>
```