# Rails call a method from within a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to call a method of one controller from within a different view.
I saw the following post [Rails call destroy method from within another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088645/rails-call-destroy-method-from-within-another-controller), but I am doing something wrong with my implementation.

The method I am trying to call is in an accessor controller.

```
    def remove_permission_from_index
      Accessor.find(params[:id]).destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
```

This controller also has the following strong param method

```
def accessor_params
  params.require(:accessor).permit(:accessor_id, :access_rights, :task_id)
end
```

My view is calling the following code

```
  <%= link_to 'Delete', {:controller => "accessors", :accessor => elem} ,method: :remove_permission_from_index, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>      </p>
```

where elem an element within a set that is defined in the task controller

```
@canEdit = Accessor.select(:task_id).where("accessor_id = ? AND access_rights = ?", current_user, true)
@canEdit.each do |p|
    p.task = Task.find(p.task_id)
```

When I am running my code I am getting the following error

```
param not found: accessor
    def accessor_params
      params.require(:accessor).permit(:accessor_id, :access_rights, :task_id)
    end
end
```

and I can see that the accessor param is not being passed :

```
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"remove_permission_from_index"}
```

a) why is the accessor_params is being called if I am trying to access a different method
b) what am I doing wrong? After all I do set `:accessor => elem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a copy paste error but:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', {:controller => "accessors", :accessor => elem} ,method: :remove_permission_from_index, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>      </p>
```

should be more like:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', {:controller => "accessors", :action => :remove_permission_from_index, :accessor => elem}, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>      </p>
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay in my comment, but these results in in the following error No route matches `{:action=>"remove_permission_from_index", :controller=>"accessors", :accessor=>#<Accessor id: nil, task_id: 12>}`, any suggestion on how to map the method to a route ?